# in java how to make sure the passed object is modified by only object to which it is passed?

Tags: java

Suppose that I have a class which takes an array of Key object to construct an object of class keyHandler, like this:

```
class KeyHandler {
    Key[] keys;
    public KeyHandler(Key[] keys) {
        this.keys=keys 
    }
    //more methods which modify key;
}
```

now I call this constructor from main

```
KeyHandler keyhandler = new KeyHandler(keys);
```

I want to make sure that keys array is not modified from main(). How can I do this?

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: You create this array in your main method, so effectively it owns it. Are you trying to prevent yourself from making changes to the variables you are declaring? Whats the goal here?

Comment: make a copy of the constructor parameter and store that in `KeyHandler` instead of the original?

Comment: you can make a copy of keys by using `System.arraycopy()` method to keep original keys wherever you like

Answer (score 0):

The KeyHandler class should create an internal copy of the key array. Then it's safe.

```
class Keyhandler {    
   private Key[] keys;
   public KeyHandler(Key[] keys) {
      this.keys = new Key[keys.length]; 
      System.arrayCopy(keys, 0, this.keys, 0, keys.length); 
   }
     //more methods which modify key;
}
```

Note, that now the keys array can't be manipulated from outside. But it would still be possible to change key properties. To be absolutely safe, you should clone the keys too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make a copy of the array in your class:

```
this.keys = Arrays.copy(keys, keys.length);
```

Note however that if the `Key` objects are mutable and your main method mutates one of the keys that you hold in your array, your local copy will observe that change too. To prevent that from happening, you can either make `Key` immutable or make a copy of each individual `Key` object (deep copy).

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by making a deep copy of the passed array.
You create a deep copy using object.clone();
You further can protect that array from external changes, by not giving direct acces, to it, or by returning  a deep copy of the array in getArray();
You further can consider using Collections.unmodifiableList();

Answer (score 0):

If `Key` is an immutable class, just clone the array:

```
this.keys = keys.clone();
```

If `Key` objects are not immutable, you will want to make a deep clone by copying the elements of the array one by one.  If `Key` has a copy constructor, the KeyHandler constructor might look like this:

```
this.keys = keys.clone();
for (int i = this.keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    this.keys[i] = new Key(this.keys[i]);
}
```

You can get more details on this practice by searching the web for "defensive copying".